# Selenium C# PhantomJs can't change viewport height

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

i have Problem setting up Viewport on PhantomJS using Selenium.

```
  webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://detectmybrowser.com/");
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080); 
        webDriver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

But when i check my browser resolution on detectmybrowser i get a resolution of 1920x4128.
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKnj.png)

I tryed to maximize the window but this didn't change anything. Please help :)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please look at the picture, when i check my viewport on a website that uses javascript to analyse viewport i get 1920x4128 and not 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS automatically expands the viewport in the scroll direction. It should report the configured viewport height when requesting `document.viewport.getHeight()` (as used on the site you're on), but it reports the expanded height. Another way to get the proper viewport height would be through `document.documentElement.clientHeight` and `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: You can report the bug in the [issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues) if you like.